# Merging two data frames with a key where a column becomes row and the other one doesn't

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame `df1` like the following:

```
A   B   key
a1  b1  001A
a2  b2  4906
a3  b3  0190
a4  b4  1993
```

and another data frame `df2` like:

```
C   D   key
c1  1  001A
c1  2  4906
c1  3  0190
c1  4  1993
c2  5  001A
c2  6  4906
c2  7  0190
c2  8  1993
```

I would like to merge them to get

```
A   B   key    c1   c2 
a1  b1  001A    1    5
a2  b2  4906    2    6
a3  b3  0190    3    7
a4  b4  1993    4    8
```

I have tried

```
pd.merge(df, df2, on='key')
```

but it isn't matching like I want. I can't seem to get the rows as columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) your `df2` to get it into the shape you want.

```
df2.pivot(index='key', columns='C', values='D')
```

```
C     c1  c2
key         
001A   1   5
0190   3   7
1993   4   8
4906   2   6
```

Then, you can join this pivot table to your `df`.

```
df.join(df2.pivot(index='key', columns='C', values='D'), on='key')
```

```
    A   B   key  c1  c2
0  a1  b1  001A   1   5
1  a2  b2  4906   2   6
2  a3  b3  0190   3   7
3  a4  b4  1993   4   8
```

Or, if you prefer, use `pd.merge`, although it's more verbose.

```
pd.merge(df, df2.pivot(index='key', columns='C', values='D'),
         left_on='key', right_index=True)
```

Comment: Perfect! Never thought of the pivot part!